# How do I create a proper bevel on narrow, pointy shapes?

Tags: bevel

I find myself running into variations of this problem with increasing frequency, where I have a narrow, curved, pointy shape like the one exemplified below, and I can't figure out how to create a bevel that isn't a mess of overlapping and clipping geometry.

[image]

Does the problem just lie in my topology, or am I going about this in entirely the wrong way?

This is what manually correcting the bevel yielded: It doesn't have the best topology, but it seems to work:
[image]

Blend File: 
[image]

Comment: could you share your mesh? maybe you have to do it in 2 times?

Comment: It seems the problem does lie in the topology and in the bevel tool that cannot cope with such a topology. It seems the only way to correct this situation currently is to manually correct the problematic area after the Bevel operation. The bevels are receiving some attention in 2.80 so there might be some improvements in the new version.

Comment: I am working in 2.8, but I added at 2.79 compatible blend file that demos the mesh. I think you're right in that it's the topology. The problem is essentially that the narrow triangular shape is narrower than the width of the bevel, and Blender doesn't know how to deal with that. It isn't an easy problem, either. If I delete those verts to open up the shape, I lose the curve information.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple bevel modes. In 2.79 If you hit "W" then "B" for the bevel tool, you can switch between them by hitting "M"[image]

Comment: This sort of works, and it may be the best blender can do on its own. It isn't quite the same result though, since the bevel isn't of a consistent width.