# Bevel weird corners

Tags: bevel

I'm new to blender, and probably there question is already answered, I just can't word it properly.

I'm trying to make a rounded corner with bevel, and it ain't working. Usually one or two corners of an object I'm making are just fine where the other corners have this sticking out going on.

[image]

I used extrude regions (vertex normal) to get those faces sit on top of each other.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131516/how-do-i-create-a-proper-bevel-on-narrow-pointy-shapes/131526#131526

Comment: This looks like loose geometry somewhere in the mesh corner which isn't get beveled but remains in place instead. It would help if you show or upload mesh before being beveled to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit your question with link

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you got that issue, but I do know how to get the effect you want.  Here's how you do it --Pardon how detailed I am being; I mean no offense :)

You start by creating the general shape using the insert and extrude tools.  You then select the corner edges as shown below, and bevel (ctrl-b).[image: instructions]

Depending on how small you go at the top, you may end up with overlapping mesh, such as the the image below, but this method should hopefully work for you.[image: OverlappingMesh]
Glad to be of any help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I figured it out. I started out with a cube added rings and extruded them. But I guess I left clicked the while extruding to re-extrude, which gave me an extra face that didn't beveled correctly

Comment: That would do it.  Doubles usually are a pain.  I'm not sure if they are ever an actual help.  Good job figuring it out!

Comment: so from the picture you stated does that mean that if u go smaller and smaller eventually it will come out sharp thing like that ?

Comment: Sort of.  The problem is that a large bevel for the base may have a larger radius than the width of the smallest section at the top.  when that happens, the bevel will run out of room and has nowhere to go, so it ends up making a mangled mesh at the top.