# Try to make a corner with curve

Tags: bevel

I working on a train game, and I try to make "rails", what are basically a square with a throgh part in middle (the dark parts), My problem is that, I want this part to turn curvy (90 degree), like I illustrated, to join vertical or horisontal rails perfectly. I can bevel the edges to be curvy, but the gap between them is larger than the gap between the straight parts.

How can I do this?

Thanks for any help!

[image: Curve]

Comment: Try to use the bevel tool in percent mode. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131516/how-do-i-create-a-proper-bevel-on-narrow-pointy-shapes/131526#131526

Answer (score 3):

Starting from the profile of the rails, you can use the spin tool:

[image]